# Android CursorAdapter not calling newView

Tags: android, listactivity

I'm creating an email interface that populates a ListView from a database using a custom CursorAdapter. The items in this ListView then display an email thread, which in very similar fashion populates a ListView using a CursorAdapter. The problem that I am having is that the second ListView will not populate.

The code for initializing both of these adapters is nearly identical (we can say they are for all intents and purposes) and through the use of log statements, I have been able to verify that the cursor being passed to the second adapter is not empty and contains all of the data that it should. What seems to be the problem is that the newView method is never called. I've tried to investigate why this is happening and have come up with nothing. What I'm wondering is why the newView method would not be called. Where is this call supposed to be triggered from?

Here is the onCreate method for the ListActivity.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.email_view);

    cursor = EmailActivity.dbAdapter.fetchEmailThread(getIntent().getStringExtra("senderUsername"));
    Log.i(TAG, getIntent().getStringExtra("senderUsername") + " " + cursor.getCount() + " " + cursor.getColumnCount());
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    adapter = new EmailViewCursorAdapter(this, cursor);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

And here is the code from the adapter, just the constructor and newView method.

```
public EmailViewCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c, true);
    inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    usernameInd = c.getColumnIndex("sender_username");
    createdInd = c.getColumnIndex("created_at");
    bodyInd = c.getColumnIndex("body");
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Made it here - new view");

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.email_view_item, parent, false);

    TextView senderName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sender_username);
    TextView timeString = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sent_time);
    TextView emailBody = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email_body);

    senderName.setText(cursor.getString(usernameInd));
    if(senderName.getText().equals(DataManager.getUser().getUsername()))
        senderName.setTextColor(0x999999);

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date sent = format.parse(cursor.getString(createdInd));
        timeString.setText(EmailModel.createTimeText(sent));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        timeString.setText("");
    }

    emailBody.setText(cursor.getString(bodyInd));

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Is newView never called?  CursorAdapter reuses views, so you it won't get called for every row.  What's in your bindView?  Any errors in the log?  (BTW, you should move the code that sets the TextView values into bindView).

Comment: To be completely honest, I'm actually letting bindView do all the work and calling it from newView. I did some copy/paste to present the question clearly. I wasn't sure which was best practice, but it doesn't make a difference in regards to this issue. To answer the question, the log statement at the beginning of newView is NEVER displayed. I can only imagine it has something to do with multiple cursors being open, but other than that, I'm stumped.

Comment: OK, I'm stumped too.  Have you tried adding a view to display when the list is empty (i.e. in the `ListActivity` layout with `@id/android:empty` as the id)? That would at least let you know whether the framework thinks there's anything in the list to display.

Comment: I believe I have resolved the issue. I tried circumventing the problem as you suggested by implementing a different adapter, which also did not cause the list to appear. Then I readjusted the view properties and the list appeared for both adapter implementations. I thought the way I was creating the views was nearly identical in the inbox and thread views, but the nested layouts in the header portions was slightly different which must have had something to do with the issue. At any rate, thanks for the assistance.

Comment: "readjusted the view properties"?

Comment: hi what you mean by readjusted your view properties  ?? please explain

Comment: Please share the answer

Answer (score 2):

inorder to call newView in every row you have to define

```
    @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    }
```